# Trying to call cognito token from postman script

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, postman-pre-request-script

Working within Postman I'm trying to call a jwtToken from Cognito using node's aws-sdk but I'm getting the following error:

> There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'

This is my scrypt:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var authenticationData = {
    Username: 'username',
    Password: 'password',
};
var authenticationDetails = new 
AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
var poolData = {
    UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_xxxxxx',
    ClientId: 'xxxxx'
};
var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
    Username: 'username',
    Pool: userPool
};
var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function(result) {
        var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
        var idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken;
    },
});
pm.globals.set("token", idToken);
```

So far the only commands I ran where: *brew install node*  and *npm install aws-sdk*

I'm sure I'm missing some sort of configuration to call the module, Any help will do! Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Postman Sandbox cannot obtain a script's external dependencies.

You can leverage `eval()` Javascript function to import additional Javascript code by having the code stored within a postman global or environment variable.

Example: `eval(postman.getGlobalVariable('aws-sdk-code'))`

See TIP #5: http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/07/28/api-testing-tips-from-a-postman-professional/

Also, you might encounter a later issue once the code executes as it seems you are requesting for `AmazonCognitoIdentity` class in the `amazon-cognito-identity-js` package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js